# How to pass Unity container to child page from window for DI

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection

I managed to set up DI using Unity:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

    container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>();

    container.RegisterType<MainWindowViewModel>();
    container.RegisterType<PageConsignmentsViewModel>();

    container.RegisterType<MainWindow>();
    container.RegisterType<PageConsignments>();

    var mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    var pc = container.Resolve<PageConsignments>();
    mainWindow.Show();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [Dependency]
    public MainWindowViewModel ViewModel
    {
        set => DataContext = value;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private Page currentPage;
    public Page CurrentPage { get { return currentPage; } set { currentPage = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPage"); } }

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;

    public MainWindowViewModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;

        CurrentPage = new PageConsignments();
    }

    #region Navigation Menu Commands
    ...
    #endregion
}
```

And I can see that `Db` has been injected into `MainWindow` and the `DataContext` is correct (new instance of `MainWindowViewModel`).

However, when I navigate to `ConsignmentsPage` with `CurrentPage = new PageConsignments` I can see that the `ConsingmentsPage.DataContext` is null - presumably because this new view is not sitting in my Unity container.

I think I managed to resolve this by navigating with :

```
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>();
    container.RegisterType<PageConsignmentsViewModel>();
    var pc = container.Resolve<PageConsignments>();
    CurrentPage = pc;
```

instead, but I was wondering - Is that the recommended method, or is there some way that I can define all these DIs in `App.OnStartup` rather than creating a new container for every navigation?

Comment: Why not inject the `PageConsignments` into the view model just like the db?

Comment: shouldn't really be passing the container around. Are you doing View First navigation or ViewModel First navigation?

Comment: If you add unitycontainer to every constructor , doesn't it inject?

Comment: The following article should provide you with a lot of help https://www.mesta-automation.com/wpf-navigation-with-dependency-injection-diioc-part-1/

Comment: This is more of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Andy That does work -thank you. Now I just need to work out which approach is actually better

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks again nkosi - injecting `PageConsignments` also works - I'll check that article and try figure out which way is best